# Где лучше хранить данные, при необходимости частого добавления/удаления

Tags: android

Есть приложение, которое собирает некоторую статистику и отправляет ее на сервер. Требуется хранить данные, которые были собраны, но еще не отправлены. Данные собираются порциями примерно по 1кб. За сутки может быть около 20Мб. Отправка данных идет не постоянно, а по требованию. После отправки данные в приложении не требуются и должны быть удалены. Вопрос в том, как лучше организовать хранилище? Мне видится два варианта: база данных или файлы. База данных выглядит лучшим вариантом, но есть сомнения насколько хорошо это будет при постоянном удалении данных из базы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

БД для этого и созданы. Это нормальная рабочая ситуация когда когда совершается множество CRUD операций. Насколько хорошо при частом удалении? Точно не хуже чем частое удаление вручную из файловой системы. При большом количестве запросов к базе данных, Realm будет отличным решением.

Comment: Realm, скорее всего, не будет верным выбором в указанном в вопросе случае. Realm создан для хранения объектов. Заворачивать просто данные в объекты только ради Realm-a будет расточительно.